# Trouble editing Google Sheet with Google App Script API (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to run a script using the google app script API which will update values on a google sheet. I've tested the google script and it works correctly with the sheet, and I've tested my connection to the script using the google app script API and the connection is successful (I can successfully log variables that are passed into the script through my C# program).  When I call the script through the C# application, the script runs and the passed in variables are logged, but the google sheet is not changed, even though running the script through the script editor does interact with the google sheet.  I've added both the drive and spreadsheets scripts to my scopes.  Why isn't the google sheet being interacted with when using the C# app?

```
C# APP:
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Script.v1;
using Google.Apis.Script.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PPR
{
    class googleAPI
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/script-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Apps Script Execution API .NET Quickstart";

        public googleAPI()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/script-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Apps Script Execution API service.
            string scriptId = "MPD2B-0a8Q2KsDHoHVPh1HVhXBvIk9FTo";
            var service = new ScriptService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Create an execution request object.
            ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest();
            //request.Function = "updateCells";
            request.Function = "callWeeklyHours";
            request.DevMode = true;

            IList<object> values = new List<object>();
            values.Add("tempProj");
            values.Add("Ben");
            //request.Parameters = values;

            ScriptsResource.RunRequest runReq =
                    service.Scripts.Run(request, scriptId);

            try
            {
                // Make the API request.
                Operation op = runReq.Execute();
            }
            catch (Google.GoogleApiException e)
            {
                // The API encountered a problem before the script
                // started executing.
                Console.WriteLine("Error calling API:\n{0}", e);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}

Google Script:

function callWeeklyHours()
{
    updateCells("New Project","Ben");
}

function updateCells(projectName, projectManager)
{  
    Logger.log(projectName + ', ' + projectManager);
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var foundPage = false;
    for(var i = 0; i<sheetnames().length; i++){    
        if(("" +sheetnames()[i]).split(" ")[0] == projectManager){
            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetnames()[i]));
            foundPage = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(projectName);


    if(foundPage == false){
        ui.alert('Project Manager Sheet Does Not Exist', 'The project manager in charge of this project has not created a sheet (a sheet named ' + projectManager + ' does not exist). Project information will not be entered.', ui.ButtonSet.OK)
        return;
    }
    var response = ui.prompt('Enter New Project', 'Store project name in which 
cell?', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    try{


  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(response.getResponseText()).setValue(projectName);
    }
    catch (e){
    var invalidInput = ui.alert('Invalid Cell Input', 'The cell name was invalid - project information was not entered', ui.ButtonSet.OK)
    }    

}

function sheetnames() { // Contributed by ahab facit, 2011
    var out = new Array()
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
    return out  
}
```

Comment: This might help with troubleshooting.  I see that you are calling SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().  Is there a valid "active sheet" in this context?  Perhaps you need to explicitly reference your spreadsheet by document id.

Comment: Ah that could be, thanks! I'm very new to google scripting - would you be able to tell me how I would reference a page from the google sheet so that I can change a value using the document ID?  I've tried the openById function, but that still hasn't been connecting properly.

Comment: Here is the function: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)  See the note at the top to determine the id value to use.

Comment: Perfect, I got it to connect to the sheet and successfully add a new page!  Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: If you don't mind, I have one last question: Is it possible to open the google sheet and interact with it through the c# app?  I've succesfully connected the app through the script to the google sheet, but my overall goal is to pull up a UI prompt on the google sheet to allow the user to type the cell for the data to get stored.  Is this possible?

Comment: I suspect that if you want access to the Spreadsheet UI you will need to initiate the call with google app script.  If you are connecting from another platform, I believe you will need to treat the app script as a web service.